# In Freemarker how do I insert the right number of spaces to place text in a specified column?

Tags: freemarker

I'm doing some simple C code generation using Freemarker. I am generating a line like the following:

```
#define MY_CONSTANT                   (0)
```

From a template of the form:

```
#define ${name}                   (${value})
```

I am generating a bunch of these and I want them to come out like this

```
#define MY_CONSTANT                   (0)
#define MY_NEW_CONSTANT               (42)
#define MY_OTHER_CONSTANT             (101)
```

With the values all column aligned. Is there an easy way to do this? Do I need to write a directive for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `right_pad` builtin.

```
#define ${name?right_pad(30)} (${value})
```

See the doc [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_right_pad).

Comment: You're a savior